# How to build a Real Size Drupal+Civi Test Configuration?

Tags: installation, testing

I have installed a Drupal+Civi test site, with same software level as my production site (Drupal 7.54 / Civi 4.7.16).

To be able to make real size tests, I want to have identical DBs on each site.

So, I have copied both prod DBs (Drupal and Civi) into my test DBs (using phpmyadmin / Copy structure and data + DROP TABLE).

Tables now seem identical (statistically : I have no real comparison tool)

I have updated settings.php with the same table "prefix"

But when I open the test site, I get an error : "Fatal error: Call to undefined function webform_menu_to_arg() in /home/bapaparoisse/www/dev/includes/menu.inc on line 824".

I must have missed something, but what ?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Could one possible cause be the fact that I have not installed most of the Modules of my Prod configuration, on my test one (e.g. my test config does not have Webform Module installed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error doesn't indicate a problem with your database - and it does sound like you've copied them correctly.  This error indicates that you have a missing file in your file system.  Is the webform module missing on your test site?  Or perhaps the test site's webform module isn't the same version?

You should also clear your Drupal cache on the test site.

Comment: You are right Jon : now that I have also copied all the Modules to test sites/all/modules, the error has disappeared.